# Windows Workflow Foundation compatibility issues

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, workflow-foundation-4

I can't, for the life of me, find any reference as to which versions of VS are compatible with WF4.

At work, I currently have VS 2013 Express for Windows Desktop installed (I run a Windows 7 machine), along with .NET 4.5.1, and it seems to be incompatible with WF4, which I'm trying to learn how to use.
I've read a lot of documentation from MSDN, but haven't found anything saying if there's a specific version of VS compatible with WF4.
Neither Workflow project template is availabe at the New Project menu, nor the sample solution I've downloaded from MSDN is successfully loaded.
Could you help me, please?

Comment: Have you searched for "activity" in VS? If I recall correctly there isn't a project type for workflow. You can add activities to any project type. There are two types of activities (code and xaml)

Answer (score 1):

Express editions didn't come with Workflow templates.

For learning WF4 you can use the [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) which comes with workflow templates.